# How do I write the equals (==) function?

Tags: wren

```
class Character {
  
    construct new(name,life){
        _name = name
        _life = life
    }
    
    name  { _name }
    life  { _life }
}
```

If the `name` and `life` are the same, it should return `true` otherwise `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Character {
  
    construct new(name,life){
        _name = name
        _life = life
    }
    
    name  { _name }
    life  { _life }
    
    ==(other){
        return _name == other.name && 
               _life == other.life
    }
}

var player_one = Character.new("Nova",100)
var player_two = Character.new("Mint Hot Chocolate",50)
var player_three = Character.new("Nova",100)

System.print(player_one == player_three) // Output: true
System.print(player_one == player_two) // Output: false
```